# I am creating a service to create PDF(say from html to PDF) using python.

Tags: css, python-2.7, wkhtmltopdf, python-pdfkit

Initially tried it using [pdfkit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit), but it doesn't support [@page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@page) so the styles which are given for printed documents are not included in the result. Can someone provide an alternative for the above issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [WeasyPrint](http://weasyprint.org/)

WeasyPrint is a visual rendering engine for HTML and CSS that can export to PDF

Comment: Thanks. I ran into to this after I post this question. Will be trying this out. Thanks again for ur response.